# Syntax error--passing "double" as primitive type to map

Tags: java

So I found source code that presumably parses a mathematical expression and calculates the answer.  However, the code contains a syntax error when declaring a new map.  This new map is supposed to hold a String and a number.  I do know that maps can't reference primitive types, like double, though.  How can I resolve this issue?

```
private Map<String, double=""> user_var = new HashMap<String, double="">();
```

To see the rest of the code, one can visit [here](http://tapas4web.blogspot.com/2011/05/mathematical-expression-parser-in-java.html)

Thank you

Comment: `Map<String, Double>` is the closest you can get.

Comment: Wow, I thought I had tried that already and still got the syntax error.  However, this did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: I checked that code in the meantime. I was worried it may expect the map to return a default value for a non-present key. However, that is not the case: everything will work as soon as you correct that one mistake. A funny mistake, though.

Comment: BTW: You don't need to wrap a `String` with another String and you don't need to autobox doubles manually e.g. `user_var.put(new String("ANS"), new Double(ans));` can be replaced with `user_var.put("ANS", ans);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an incorrect declaration. Correct would be:

```
private Map<String, Double> user_var = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [TObjectDoubleHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectDoubleHashMap.html) with allows a String key and a `double` value.

Comment: I studied his code sample, it is meant to work with `Double`s. It doesn't even rely on autoboxing.

Comment: He doesn't appear to need the `double` value to be `null`. Using a plain `Map` might be simpler.

Comment: He was just looking how to fix code he found on the Web. I don't think he's interested in changing anything beyond fixing the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();`

Thanks to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) you can use it like

```
map.put("one",1d);
double d = map.get("one");
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` can't contain a primitive of any kind. You can create one using the wrapper class for `double` though:

```
private Map<String, Double> user_var = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

This can then be used (almost) exactly as if it contained doubles:

```
double value = 2.3;
user_var.put("myVar", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java has *wrapper classes* that allow you to use a primitive type where an Object is required. The wrapper class for the primitive type double is named Double. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Double.html) for details.